# C++ waiting for response asynchronously, best design?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a program with a main loop which must keep running. Sometimes requests will be made to the network so I defer them to a request making service which spawns another thread. What is the best way to act on the eventual response?

My idea is to set a variable when making the request, protect it by a mutex and have the service thread flip the variable when it is finished, with the response. This means I must continually check the variable in the main loop. Is this the best way?

I'm familiar with async programming in Javascript, but there there is only one thread, so a callback can do all the work safely.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm using C++ 17.

Comment: C++11 added std::async and std::future. They sound like what you could use to acomplish the task. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński thank you, std::future's wait_for(0) seems like a good bet (as I cannot pause the loop)

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment just made me find this: https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue. What do you make of it?

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of traffic I would use a thread to perform the networking, use an "IPC" object containing a mutex, deque and condition-variable.

Use a `std::shared_ptr` to share the IPC to both main and thread contexts.

When the thread receives the message, it will lock the mutex (use `std::lock_guard`) and push the message to the deque.  Outside the lock, then signal the condition-variable.

The main thread would wait on the condition-variable, when signalled it will then lock the mutex and pop anything from the deque.  Note that you use the mutex to protect *only* the deque.

.

Another approach would be to use a `std::async` method to receive the message and the main program would wait on it with the `get` method which will wait until the async method completes.

I'd put the choice largely down to how much networking you are intending to do; if only an occasional "open-send-receive-close" transaction then certainly look at using async.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion seems good in the general case. I will try to use std::future::wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) and see if it works/if the performance is OK.

Comment: Take a look at YouTube video `iCL6GYoi1RU` for an introduction to using `std::async` from Jason Turner - "C++ Weekly - Ep 9 std::future Quick-Start" -   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCL6GYoi1RU